# Labeling only one tick mark but having other tick marks on x-axis

Tags: pgfplots

The code provided has pgfplots mark 5 tick marks on the x-axis (at increments of 5 starting at 5). I would like to have only one extra tick mark labeled - the one at 2.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=27,
    domain=-2:27,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-100,ymax=3200,
    restrict y to domain=-100:3200,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={},
    extra x ticks={5, 10, 15, 20, 25},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0.025574:25,blue] {5*x^2 + 80 / x} node[anchor=west,pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize]{$y = 5x^{2} + \dfrac{80}{x}$};
\draw [fill] (2,60) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Set `xtick={5,10,...,25}, extra x ticks={2}`.

Comment: @Jake  I added the specifications `xtick={5,...,25},ytick={},` `extra x ticks={2},` and `extra x tick labels={2}.`  I prefer not to have the labels 5, 10, 15, 20, and 25 printed, though.  I want the tick marks but not these labels.  I do want the label 2.

Comment: Then set `xtick={5,...,25}, xticklabels={}, extra x ticks={2}`.

Comment: @Jake  Here is what I have in my code.  `xtick={5,10,...,25},ytick={},` `xticklabels={},` and 
`extra x ticks={2},`.  There are no labels for the tick marks.  I just want the label 2.

Comment: @Jake  I added the specification `extra x tick labels={2},`.  Now, one of the tick marks is labeled "2."

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Could you include an image of what you want the final result to look like?

Comment: @Jake  Please tell me how to include the image of what I wanted depicted.  I could also send you the code.  If you prefer to have the code that I implemented, tell me how to send it to you.  It has too many characters for the comment-box.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant now. Set `tick={5,10,...,25}, xticklabels={}, extra x ticks={2}, extra x tick style={xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}`

Answer (score 8):

Set

```
xtick={5,10,...,25},
xticklabels={},
extra x ticks={2},
extra x tick style={xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=27,
    domain=-2:27,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-100,ymax=3200,
    restrict y to domain=-100:3200,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={5,10,...,25},
    xticklabels={},
    extra x ticks={2},
    extra x tick style={xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=0.025574:25,blue] {5*x^2 + 80 / x} node[anchor=west,pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize]{$y = 5x^{2} + \dfrac{80}{x}$};
\draw [fill] (2,60) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```